# Bulk editing of Fields on multiple entities

Tags: 7, forms

What is the best way to do the following?

- Open up a page that does a form callback from hook_menu
- Based on a URL arg, load all entities (probably with EFQ) with that argument
- Present certain fields on the entities to edit, with one Submit button at the bottom
- On Submit, each of these are processed and saved within their respective Entities

As a bonus, it would be great if the form output each set of fields in a tabular format, like editing a grid (without jQuery plugins needed).

The first two I can do, but I am not seeing seperation of entity data in the form submit data (knowing which data goes with which entity_id).

What I am trying to do is provide a quick way of editing game results line by line (Team A (score_home property) vs Team B (score_away property)).

Answer (score 0):

The [Multiple forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiform) module might point you in the right direction.

Here is a quote from its project page:

> This is an API module which lets you put several forms into one `<form>`.